# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError during Jmeter execution

Tags: jmeter

Getting below error message during our load test in jmeter version 5.1.1.

```
2020-01-17 01:30:00,644 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How much Max memory should we increase in jmeter batch file using command:

```
HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

Answer (score 1):

BlazeMeter [article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) recommends:

> Just increase the maximum heap size to ~80% of your total available physical RAM.
>
> HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
>
> Now change the -Xmx value accordingly. For example: if you want to set the maximum heap > size to 4 gigabytes, you’ll need to change the line to: HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx4096m"

Answer (score 1):

As per [Optimal Heap Size](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/Java.html#Java-Garbage_Collection-Optimal_Heap_Size) chapter:

> "If the occupancy of the Java heap is too high, garbage collection occurs frequently. If the occupancy is low, garbage collection is infrequent but lasts longer... Try to keep the memory occupancy of the Java heap between 40% and 70% of the Java heap size... The highest point of occupancy of the Java heap is preferably not above 70% of the maximum heap size, and the average occupancy is between 40% and 70% occupancy. If the occupancy goes over 70%, resize the Java heap."
>
> "A correctly sized Java heap should always have a memory occupancy of between 40% and 70% of the maximum Java heap size. To ensure that the occupancy does not exceed 70%, set the maximum Java heap size to at least 43% larger than the Maximum occupancy value provided by GCMV. This setting then makes the Maximum value 70% of the Java heap and the average to be above 40% of the Java heap size."

[image]

So make sure that:

1. JMeter has enough headroom to operate
2. [Garbage Collection](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/garbage-collection-java/) doesn't happen too often

Use [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) to monitor the heap usage by JMeter and tune minimum/maximum according to the above 40% - 70% rule